# Embedding external javascript library in single place in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want to add external Javascript library to my GWT application. The library should be downloaded from external location or can be placed in my webapp folder. I want to call its methods from GWT JSNI.

I know that I can add  tag into HTML file of my GWT app. But a problem is that I dont want to load that library in all the places of my GWT application. I want to load it only if user opens some Widget. The reason for this is that the library runs some script on load.

So how can I incorporate external Javascript library into some GWT widget without placing it into GWT application HTML page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GWT ScriptInjector:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html